# Is possible rename a folder with files?

Tags: vba, outlook

Is possible rename a folder with files?
The code below create a folder and save the attachments in there. After I need to rename this folder with a date which is in the second line of file saved.
I can retrieve the date, but the code can't rename the folder.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SalvarAnexo(Item)

    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim strData As String
    Dim caminhoTemp As String
    Dim caminhoFinal As String
    Dim caminhoFtp As String

    'MsgBox "Mensagem Recebida de " & Item.Sender & "!"
    caminhoTemp = "C:\temp"
    caminhoFinal = "C:\"


    For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
        If Right$(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "TXT" Then
            Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
            FileName = caminhoTemp & "\" & Atmt.FileName
            Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
            Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, 1)
            strData = objFile.ReadLine
            strData = objFile.ReadLine
            strData = Left$(strData, 10)
            strData = Replace(strData, "-", "")

            caminhoFinal = caminhoFinal & strData

            Name caminhoTemp As caminhoFinal
            objFile.Close


            MsgBox "Your date is " & strData
        End If
    Next Atmt

End Sub
```

Comment: First you the destination folder c:\ already exists. Second what you are effectively doing is renaming the folder with an empty name. try doing what you just tried to do in code by hand and you will see the problem. What you really want to do is move the content of the temp folder into the final location instead.

Comment: Close the file first, then rename the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
objFSO.MoveFolder("c:\oldname", "c:\newname")
```

The files in the "oldname" folder should be all closed.

**Edit** per Tomalak below (thanks!):

You can get the folder object and rename it:

```
    Set fdr = objFSO.GetFolder("oldname")
    fdr.Name = "newname"
```

The files in the "oldname" folder should be all closed.

"oldname" is Fullsplec.

"newname" is just the name.

Comment: I think you can also simply set the [`Name` property of the Folder object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zawxett8(v=vs.84).aspx).

Comment: I don't have to, because the documentation says I can. ;)

Comment: I used this:
Set fdr = objFSO.GetFolder(caminhoTemp)

fdr.Name = strData

But returns me a ERRO of access

Comment: @caezar Providing you got the fdr object OK and the strData is not violating naming rules, you might not have the rights to rename the forlder you are trying to rename in the location it is in. Or it's something entirely different... One thing is for sure: the code above works (for me, on my machine).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly without the overhead of the `FileScriptingObject` with

```
Name "C:\oldname" As "C:\newname"
```

In your particular case there isn't a huge saving as the `FileScriptingObject` has been invoked already to open the text file.

Comment: This is the simplest solution here yet (if the OP does not absolutely have to use FSO for renaming).